# mobX: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I just playground with some code with mobX, and this happened, don't know why but i'm sure it not much different from offical docs

Here is **store.tsx**

```
import { observable, computed, action, makeObservable, override, makeAutoObservable } from "mobx"

class CounterStore {
  initValue = 0
  powValue = Math.pow(this.initValue, 2)
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }
  increaseNumber() {
    this.initValue = this.initValue + 1
  }
}
const Store = new CounterStore()
export default Store
```

Here is where i use this. called **increasement.tsx**

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react"

export const IncrementButton = observer(({ store }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={store.increaseNumber}>Increase</button>
      <h1>{store.initValue}</h1>
    </div>
  )
})
```

And **index.tsx**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <IncrementButton store={Store} />
    {/* <TestUseState /> */}
    {/* <TestEffect />
     <UseMemoTest /> */}
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root"),
```

Weird is, it show `initValue`, but when i click increase it show `can't not read properties`
Please help, thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

as @mimoid noticed, your method is not bound to the class and losing context (`this`). It is not MobX problem, it is just regular javascript feature called  [late binding](https://javascript.info/bind).

Although you don't really need to change `makeAutoObservable` to `makeObservable`, you can just use arrow functions, in my opinion it is more "native" way:

```js
class CounterStore {
  initValue = 0
  powValue = Math.pow(this.initValue, 2)
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)
  }
  // Just make it an arrow function
  increaseNumber = () => {
    this.initValue = this.initValue + 1
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can pass `autoBind` option to the `makeAutoObservable`:

> autoBind: true uses action.bound/flow.bound by default, rather than action/flow. Does not affect explicitly annotated members.

https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html#options-

Comment: Saved me there. who would believe that changing it to an arrow function will solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change `makeAutoObservable` to `makeObservable` and manually
assign `action.bound` to every action instead of `action`.
I had a similar error and it solved it.